# Extract From <Response>

Tags: html, dom

I have a URL which is a response XML data like the one below. I'm using VBA in Excel. I want to extract "102196", which is located at the bottom of the data, but it's not working.

Code:

```vb
With Http
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

On Error Resume Next
add = Html.querySelector("zestimate").getAttribute("amount")
```

XML:

```xml
<response>
  <results>
    <result>
      <zpid>154607080</zpid>
      <links>
        <homedetails>
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2912-W-1st-St-APT-1-Jacksonville-FL-32254/154607080_zpid/
</homedetails>
        <graphsanddata>
http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2912-W-1st-St-APT-1-Jacksonville-FL-32254/154607080_zpid/#charts-and-data
</graphsanddata>
        <mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/154607080_zpid/</mapthishome>
        <comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/154607080_zpid/</comparables>
      </links>
      <address>
        <street>2912 W 1st St APT 1</street>
        <zipcode>32254</zipcode>
        <city>Jacksonville</city>
        <state>FL</state>
        <latitude>30.339737</latitude>
        <longitude>-81.716677</longitude>
      </address>
      <zestimate>
        <amount currency="USD">102196</amount>
```